# Show a modal window with a progress during ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, excel, codeigniter

I have an excel sheet which contains +30000 records, I insert every record into database, I would like to show a modal window with a progress bar and percentage of completion including total no of records, # of records inserted, # of failed records etc. I am not able to update the labels I have mentioned. I have tried with jQuery, but I am not able to set the value at runtime to javascript variable to increase the records inserted value.
I am using PHP (Codeigniter) to insert every records into database.

I am new in Jquery and php. Please help. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you could accomplish this. You could upload the entire file and have PHP process it (which I think would be quicker and more efficient). The problem would be getting an accurate read on the progress of the PHP inserting each row into the database. You could use flush() to output something back to the browser that jQuery would listen for, but I don't think that that would be the best way.

The other way would be to have jQuery process the file and update the progress bar and counts. The problem that might arise with this is the number of rows that you are trying to insert into the database -- 30,000 records might be quite a bit, but here's how I'd try it.

First you'll need a jQuery plugin: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/

I put comments into the jQuery script so you can target your modal box and show when to do ajax, etc.

Here's the data file that I used saved as a local *.csv file:

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
e,5
f,6
g,7
h,8
I,9
j,10
```

But basically you parse the csv file and submit each row/record up to the PHP server for inserting into the database. Upon each successful response via ajax, you update the progress bar and counter (both successful and errors).

http://jsfiddle.net/dmayo2/u3kqgjLy/

Here's the relevant code piece:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(file);
reader.onload = function(event) {
   // process csv file
}
```

My 2¢

Comment: Thanks for the example. That's works great for .csv but i need to import .xls file. I need some script similiar to your script to read excel file. any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know of any direct way to read an excel file by jQuery (xls is basically a binary file rather than plain text). You'll probably have to convert the xls to either xml or csv. You could upload the xls file and let php convert, then send back down to the browser to parse (I still think that jQuery will work better with progress bar, etc. You could try this if you want PHP to do all the work: https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I convert xls file to csv file using php. I know that wasn't good idea to show progress during importing, because it make the process slower. but I need to keep users entertained while importing large data.